# How to convert a WAV file into a 3gp in Android using MediaCodec

Tags: wav, android-mediacodec, 3gp

I have tried to perform the with the following conversion loop.

```
    while (true) {
        sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer, 0)
        if (sampleSize < 0) break
        val presentationTimeUs = extractor.sampleTime
        val flags = extractor.sampleFlags

        val inputBufferId = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(codecTimeoutUs)

        if (inputBufferId >= 0) {
            val codecBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId)
            codecBuffer?.put(inputBuffer)
            codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, sampleSize, presentationTimeUs, flags)
        }

            extractor.advance()
       

        val outputBufferId = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, codecTimeoutUs)

        if (outputBufferId >= 0) {
            val codecBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId)
            muxer.writeSampleData(outputTrackIndex, codecBuffer!!, bufferInfo)
            codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, false)
        }
    }
```

The results are a an invalid .3gp file, can you help me?.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet doesn't show how `MediaExtractor`, `MediaCodec` and `MediaMuxer` are configured, so the picture is incomplete.

In general, the auxiliary `inputBuffer` must be cleared before writing and flipped before reading.

But it's easier to let the codec manager the buffers:

```
val inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId)!!
val sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer, 0)
```

Additionally, if the `sampleSize` is negative, you should consider it to be the end of the file and notify the codec:

```
codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM)
```